# How to make Maven automatically retry (resume from failed module)?

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, build, maven-plugin

I'm working on a large Maven project consisting of a number of different modules. The Maven build intermittently fails on certain modules but if all is well, a simple manually invoked `--resume-from` (sometimes on a couple of different modules) will allow it to continue to success.

*Am deliberately omitting the details of exactly why this happens - suspect it may be due to Windows file locking on files in the target folder - but that's not the point of the question.*

**Question:** Is it possible to get Maven to automatically retry (maybe just once, or maybe up to 3 times), resuming from the failed module?

**Thoughts:** The only way I can currently think of doing it is via a batch file, which reads the last line and somehow extracts the module name to resume from - but that doesn't look easy. Don't want to reinvent the wheel and was wondering if there's a nice Maven plugin that already does the job?

Comment: That should be easier with Maven 4.0.0 (Q1 2021): see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65380723/6309)

Comment: @VonC laughing at this from aug 2023

Comment: @spy True, that should be simpler now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a fully fledged batch file, using [Anitha.R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54305409#54457884) as a starting point.

**Usage instructions:**

1. Ensure the Maven executable is in the [Windows path](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html).
2. Ideally also ensure that a version of tee for Windows is in the Windows path. *(E.g. I'm use the one provided as part of [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win), having added Git's `usr\bin` folder to my path).*
3. Copy the batch file code into a new file.
4. Change the `max_retries` value as desired.
5. Save as "mvnretry.bat" in a folder in the Windows path.
6. Run in the same way as [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-embedder/cli.html), e.g. `mvnretry clean install -Pmyprofile -DskipTests`.

**Batch file code:**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set max_retries=3
set retry_count=0
set output_file=%date:/=%%time::=%
set output_file=%output_file: =0%
set output_file=%temp%\mvn%output_file:.=%.out
set mvn_command=call mvn %*
set tee_found=true
where /q tee
if not errorlevel 1 goto retry
  set tee_found=false
  echo tee.exe not found in system path^^! Build will continue but output will be delayed...
:retry
  echo %mvn_command%
  if %tee_found%==true (
    %mvn_command% | tee %output_file%
  ) else (
    %mvn_command% > %output_file%
    type %output_file%
  )
  echo Parsing output...
  set "resume_from="
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('type %output_file% ^| find "mvn <goals> -rf"') do (
    set resume_from=%%i
  )
  if !retry_count! LSS %max_retries% if not [%resume_from%] == [] (
    echo Resuming from %resume_from%...
    set /a retry_count=retry_count+1
    set /a retries_remaining=max_retries-retry_count
    echo Retrying... [retries used: !retry_count!, retries remaining: !retries_remaining!]
    set mvn_command=call mvn -rf :%resume_from% %*
    goto retry
  )
del /q %output_file%
endlocal
```

Answer (score 6):

I have one idea to solve your problem and maybe you don't need a batch file to do the job. You can create a Maven Core Extension and create an EventSpy library to execute --resume-from when the build fails.
I already tested this example found in this answer [Run a maven plugin when build fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893919/run-a-maven-plugin-when-the-build-fails)

Based on this answer you could use Maven Invoker [Maven Invoker](http://maven.apache.org/shared-archives/maven-invoker-2.1.1/usage.html)

yet... I found an extension to safe parallel builds [Maven Core Extensions Example for Safe Parallel Builds](https://github.com/takari/core-extensions-example)

I known you need the project info ... so looking inside of [ExecutionEvent](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/execution/ExecutionEvent.Type.html) and [MavenProject](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html) class we have all info about the current building project.

I hope it will work for you too.

Edit:

I'm looking for some extension that implements this behavior "automatically retry" when some module fails.  If I do not find anything we should create an extension to that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe achieving this using a batch script looks easy. Hope the below script works for you.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('call mvn clean install ^| find "mvn <goals> -rf"') do (
    call mvn clean install -e -rf : %%i
)
endlocal
```

*Regret that I haven't tested it.*

Comment: This may need some tweaking but for me it looks likes the path of least resistance. (I may post my own answer in future if I can get it to work reliably and possibly include retries etc.)

Comment: **Update:** The code as written here didn't work for me but provided a good starting point. Have now posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54305409#54549477) with a modified version.